# PUSH-000064 Failed to unsubscribe Client - Invalid Topic name or selector

Tags: push-diffusion

I have seen the following lines appear in the server log:

```
2016-06-12 11:21:01.524|WARN|Diffusion: InboundThreadPool
Thread_1|PUSH-000064|Failed to unsubscribe Client Android Client
d42ca1e21c6d32l6-000000030000016a CONNECTED@173.58.11.31 from '!3fga'
- Invalid Topic name or selector.|com.pushtechnology.diffusion.clients.impl.ClientImp
```

My understanding is that the client is trying to unsubscribe from a topic that does not exist.

Interestingly this log is never output for iOS clients.

Does this indicate a problem? If so, what is causing it and why does it only affect HTTP polling clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This indicates an issue that is caused by a load balancer relaying the unsubscription request to the wrong server.

You have android clients subscribing to one server and establishing a session with that server, but if that android client has been disconnected for example due to low signal or going through a tunnel, the client will attempt to reconnect. When it comes to reconnect the load balancer is directing the client to a different server which doesn't understand the topic that you are referring to when you unsubscribe.

iOS clients connecting over DPT (built directly on top of TCP) open a single socket and remain connected until the connection is no longer needed. This means that the load balancer only gets involved once, which prevents this issue from manifesting for those clients.

By using session stickiness at the load balancer based on the `Cookie` HTTP header, or Sticky-IP as outlined in the diffusion documentation [here](http://docs.pushtechnology.com/docs/latest/manual/html/administratorguide/loadbalancers/routing.html),  the client would reconnect to the same server and the problem would be avoided.